# Find Candidate With the Highest Skills Based on Skill-Set passed

Tags: node.js, api, express, crud

I am building a REST API with node.js, express.js but implementing it using Data Structures (no databases first). I have 2 routes `Post` and `Get`. My questions is, how can I implement a `get` route such that I can be able to retrieve the candidate with the most number of skill set passed as parameters: i.e.

This is my Object

```js
const candidate = [
   {"id":1, "name":"Jonh", "skills":["Python","Java","Go","Node","Express"]},
   {"id":2, "name":"Mary", "skills":["Go","Python"]},
   {"id":3, "name":"Kevin", "skills":["Ruby","Java","Go"]}
   ]
```

This is the `get` route:

```js
app.get('candidate/search', function(res,res){

 })
```

Please help

Comment: so if I pass {"javascript","Java","Node"} i should get John

Comment: You should post at least some of your tries to be reviewed here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort the candidates by skill then return the most skilled candidate using the res.json function.

The skillSortFunction will sort by number of skills in descending order, so we want to pick the first element of the sorted array.

```
const candidate = [
    {"id":1, "name":"Jonh", "skills":["Python","Java","Go","Node","Express"]},
    {"id":2, "name":"Mary", "skills":["Go","Python"]},
    {"id":3, "name":"Kevin", "skills":["Ruby","Java","Go"]}
];

function skillSortFunction(a, b) {
    return (b.skills || []).length - (a.skills || []).length;
}

app.get('candidate/search', function(res,res){
    candidate.sort(skillSortFunction);
    const mostSkilled = candidate[0];
    return res.json(mostSkilled);
})
```

A demonstration in vanilla JavaScript here:

```js
const candidate = [
    {"id":1, "name":"Jonh", "skills":["Python","Java","Go","Node","Express"]},
    {"id":2, "name":"Mary", "skills":["Go","Python"]},
    {"id":3, "name":"Kevin", "skills":["Ruby","Java","Go"]}
];

function skillSortFunction(a, b) {
    return (b.skills || []).length - (a.skills || []).length;
}

candidate.sort(skillSortFunction);
const mostSkilled = candidate[0];
console.log("Most skilled candidate:", mostSkilled);
const leastSkilled = candidate[candidate.length-1];
console.log("Least skilled candidate:", leastSkilled );
```